# Why margin-top doesn't work for <i> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.fa-caret-down{
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-top:3px;
    line-height: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><span>something</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

As you see, none of `padding` or `margin` or `line-height` don't make my expected effect. Here is expected result:

[image]

How can I get that?

**Note:** Based on my real codes, I shouldn't use `position: absolute;` for that `<i>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `margin`/`padding`/`line-height` is working, you just have to add `vertical-align:top` to `span`

```css
 span{
   vertical-align:top;
 }
.fa-caret-down{
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-top:3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><span>something</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the changes which works

```css
.fa-caret-down{
    top: 6px;
    position : relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div><span>something</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```